# How to apply Win2D Blur effect to a picture from gallery?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, win2d

I have been searching something to blur an image and i found Win2D and Nokia Lumia Sdk. I wanna use Win2D to blur an image. But im unable to assign picture from gallery to [CanvasBitmap][1]. I just want to select an image from gallery and apply blur effect using Win2D. I tried this [tutorial][2] but I couldn't assign my own image and it gives an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' to 'Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasBitmap'[1]:
```

Comment: Can you fix the links please?  That'll help anyone trying to answer this to know what you've tried already and provide some more context.

Comment: Can you please post the code that shows how you get the picture from library?